# Python dictionary replaces values

Tags: python

I'm trying to test dictionary of dictionaries in python.

The first way of initialisation works, whereas the second way replaces the values. I do not understand why.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
BASIC_SCHEME = {'name': None}

workload_names=['a', 'b']
WORKLOAD_STRUCT ={k: {} for k in workload_names}
print ("without initialisation ", WORKLOAD_STRUCT)
WORKLOAD_STRUCT['a']['name'] = 'a'
WORKLOAD_STRUCT['b']['name'] = 'b'
print(WORKLOAD_STRUCT)

WORKLOAD_STRUCT  = None


WORKLOAD_STRUCT ={k: BASIC_SCHEME for k in workload_names}

print ("with initialisation ", WORKLOAD_STRUCT)

WORKLOAD_STRUCT['a']['name'] = 'a'
WORKLOAD_STRUCT['b']['name'] = 'b'

print(WORKLOAD_STRUCT)
```

This is the results from my console.

```
 python test.py
without initialisation  {'a': {}, 'b': {}}
{'a': {'name': 'a'}, 'b': {'name': 'b'}}
with initialisation  {'a': {'name': None}, 'b': {'name': None}}
{'a': {'name': 'b'}, 'b': {'name': 'b'}}
```

Comment: It looks like your second way is creating a dictionary of references to your `BASIC_SCHEME` dictionary. Maybe add in a copy instead? `WORKLOAD_STRUCT ={k: BASIC_SCHEME.copy() for k in workload_names}`

Comment: In the first case you are creating a new dict for every `k` in `workload_names`. In the second case you are assigning a reference to the same dict to every `k` in `workload_names`. So, in the second case, when you modify the dict associated to `a` it also modifies the one associated to `b`, because they are the same dictionary.

Comment: @Dan, that's it

Comment: @tandem have a look at the edit I just made to my answer. It would probably help if you outline your goals here as I imagine this is not the best pattern to take.

Comment: The idea is that we have multiple workloads, and each workload has it's own struct. based on which workload we using, we intend to use that struct. I'm thinking of using super class for the workloads. maybe that's better... but it's hard to grow that (i don't know enough about super classes in py)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You second method creates a dictionary of references all pointing to the same object i.e. `BASIC_SCHEME`. What you want is to create a new dictionary object each time. You can use `.copy()` for this:

```
WORKLOAD_STRUCT ={k: BASIC_SCHEME.copy() for k in workload_names}
```

Some related concepts you should be aware of:

- [`copy` vs `deepcopy`](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/copy-python-deep-copy-shallow-copy/)
- (`defaultdict`)[https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/collections.html]

Comment: We can also create a copy via `dict(BASIC_SCHEME)` @Dan :)

Comment: @DeveshKumarSingh thanks, is there any advantage to casting rather than `.copy()`? I think `.copy()` is more explicit.

Comment: I don't think so, I feel `dict(BASIC_SCHEME)` to be more explicit :) Also if you think my comment was helpful, could you please upvote my answer :) @Dan

Answer (score 1):

The `BASIC_SCHEME` in your second instantiation of `WORKLOAD_STRUCT` is still pointing to the first instantiation if `WORKLOAD_STRUCT` , hence what you want to do is take a new copy of `BASIC_SCHEME` here which you can do by `dict(BASIC_SCHEME)`

```
BASIC_SCHEME = {'name': None}

workload_names=['a', 'b']
WORKLOAD_STRUCT ={k: {} for k in workload_names}
print ("without initialisation ", WORKLOAD_STRUCT)
WORKLOAD_STRUCT['a']['name'] = 'a'
WORKLOAD_STRUCT['b']['name'] = 'b'
print(WORKLOAD_STRUCT)

#Copy of BASIC_SCHEME
WORKLOAD_STRUCT ={k: dict(BASIC_SCHEME) for k in workload_names}

print ("with initialisation ", WORKLOAD_STRUCT)

WORKLOAD_STRUCT['a']['name'] = 'a'
WORKLOAD_STRUCT['b']['name'] = 'b'

print(WORKLOAD_STRUCT)
```

The output will be

```
without initialisation  {'a': {}, 'b': {}}
{'a': {'name': 'a'}, 'b': {'name': 'b'}}
with initialisation  {'a': {'name': None}, 'b': {'name': None}}
{'a': {'name': 'a'}, 'b': {'name': 'b'}}
```